# Version 12.04 or 13.04

Tags: versions

I am new to both linux and ubuntu, never used it before.
I've noticed that there is two versions available to download on the official website. For a new user, is it recommended to go with the 13.04 version directly, or the 12.04 version that has "extended support"?

Best regards

confused first time user

Comment: 12.04 in an LTS ( Long Term Support ) 4 or 5 years .. not confirm

Comment: 13.04 Not LTS 9 months support ...

Answer (score 0):

I installed 12.04 yesterday for the first time (new user) today I'm upgrading to 12.10. It has so far taken me 6 hours and it looks like its going to take six more before its completed.

With that in mind, I'd start at 12.10 if you can find it.

Comment: Than you can better go for 13.04 right away I think. I don't see any reason why you should choose an older, non-LTS release.

Comment: Yes, I think I may abandon this upgrade, download 13.04 and start again. It's only been installed for 24 hours.  Thanks

Comment: You should just consider, that since 13.04 is a completely new release, there is a much higher number of bugs and errors so far, then either the 12.04 or 12.10 versions. I am currently running 12.04, and I'm not planning on updating to 13.04 until it is pretty stable. But, still, the 13.04 is pretty sweet, and eventually, when it is more stable, and has less bugs, I'm probably going to upgrade to 13.04 ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I think it's the best version currently is 13.04. It got released 2 weeks ago and gives you access to the very latest version of the installed software. It's also the most user friendly version right now I think and that might be the most important bit for a new user. :)

The LTS (Long Term Support) release are for people who choose stability over new features. This is normally chosen by big companies for example.